# Does a asyncpg (pool connection) execute command automatically rollbacks incase of failure?

Tags: python, asyncpg

If the following code were to fail, would I need to execute a rollback before being able to acquire another connection and execute another command?

```py
import asyncpg

db_pool = asyncpg.create_pool(...)

try:
    async with db_pool.acquire() as conn:
        await conn.execute(...)
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. After some tests, I can confirm that if execute fails, an auto rollback is applied.